# Topology and Planetary Nebulae

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I apologize ahead of time if this receives any down-votes, but I was just reading a text on topology when the idea struck me: has any mathematician or, for that matter, any topologist, analyzed the formations of planetary nebulae? For example, I have found the following papers that appear to mention the word "topology," but it is from the perspective of astronomers more-so as I see it than from the perspective of topologists:

1. [A three-dimensional magnetohydrodynamic model
   of planetary nebula jets, knots, and filaments](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2008/45/aa09848-08.pdf)
2. [Morpho-kinematic modeling of planetary
   nebulae with SHAPE](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FIAU%2FIAU2_S234%2FS1743921306004029a.pdf&code=2ad3717b1e2285af3d961c531b3262e2)

Does anyone know of any papers on the subject? I imagine it is just that they are either uninteresting or no one has thought of it (but I'm certain that could not be the case).

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Are you interested in the topology of nebulae or the geometry of them or both?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am interested in the topology of nebulae from a mathematical perspective.